# .NET session null after RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Im getting this super annoying error in .net (c#), after a RedirectToAction i loose all of my Session stuff.

```
...

    Session["someStuff"] = "Super Really Nice Stuff";

    // this sid is passed, but session dont
    return RedirectToAction("method", new { sid = sid }); 
}

public ActionResult method(string sid)
{
    var someStuff = Session["someStuff"] // Session is null :s

 ....
```

Can someone help me please ? This is so annoying.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004106/mvc3-destroying-session-on-redirecttoaction

Comment: @Habib Thanks for you answer, but i already tested it and still not working, even if i remove the line sessionState ... And its the whole session not just a var.